# How to create nested serialization from mutliple models uisng django rest framewrok

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create nested relationship from more than two models in Django Rest Framework.
Thank you in advance for helping me.
I succeed with two models but when I'm trying with three models unable to create nested serialization.

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
  project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Site(models.Model):
  site_id =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  site_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  project_id= models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="projectid", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.site_name 
class Aggin(models.Model):
   assign_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   site_id = Models.ForeginKey(Site, relate_name="siteid", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Song, Artist


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
      model = Project
      fields = ('__all__')
      
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
   
  class Meta:
    model = Site
    fields = ('__all__')

class AggignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
  class Meta:
     model = Aggin
     fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: what happens, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: you have a typo in class `Aggin` here: `site_id = Models.ForeginKey`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to primary id field if you wanna use the Django's default foreign key setting. And `related_name` should be defined from the view of the counterpart model.

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
  project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Site(models.Model):
  site_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="sites", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.site_name 

class Aggin(models.Model):
   site = Models.ForeginKey(Site, relate_name="assigns", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And then, in serializer, you can set like the following.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Song, Artist

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sites = SiteSerializer(read_only = True, many = True)

    class Meta:
      model = Project
      fields = ('id', 'project_name', 'sites')
      
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assigns = AggignSerializer(read_only = True, many = True)
   
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('id', 'site_name', 'assigns')

class AggignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Aggin
        fields = ('id')
```

Comment: Thank you, actually I want to create three fields from three models project name, site name, assign to user.

Comment: Expected post   {"project_name":"test", "site_name":"site test":"assign_id":1}

Comment: You mean, you want to create three objects from that JSON data?

Comment: Your right passing JSON data

Comment: Then you can create some custom api view to deal with that JSON.

Comment: for two models I created successfully but when I am trying with three models unable to create view.

Comment: see document  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: Yeah, Project JSON data should have `sites` field which have the array of site model data and each site data of the array should have the array of assign model data.

Comment: Of course when you wanna use related field serializer for saving, then you need to remove the `read_only` attribute

Comment: can you please provide create method for three serialization. I  tried lot but no success.

Comment: Can you please add the JSON data into the post now you're using?

Comment: And the current views.py file?

Comment: Please check once I update project and site  models, created serializers for two models  ,add view.py also